# Under what conditions does $S(U) + T(U) = (S+T)(U)$ for linear operators S,T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional (real) vectors space, $U \leq V$ a linear subspace, and $S, T: V \rightarrow V$ be two linear maps. Then $(T+S)(U) \subset T(U) + S(U)$ holds clearly. What are sufficient and necessary conditions under which we have an inclusion in the opposite direction, ie. when is $(T+S)(U) = T(U) + S(U)$?

Is there a way to formulate this in terms of the inner product defined on operators as $\langle S, T\rangle = Tr(A^T B)$?

Comment: Do you mean that if $V$ and $U$ are fixed, what conditions are there on the choices of $S$ and $T$ for this to hold?

Comment: Yes, @OliverHouse

Comment: At least necessary that $T(U)=S(U)$ along the lines of for all $x,y \in U$ there is $z \in U$ such that $T(x)+S(y)=T(z)+S(z)$. Then this holds for $y=0$ in particular, and so $z, x-z \in T^{-1}(T(U) \cap S(U))$ hence $x \in T^{-1}(T(U) \cap S(U))$ and $T(U) \subset S(U)$, similarly the other way. Seems restrictive.

Comment: @undefined Why would $z \in T^{-1}(T(U) \cap S(U))$?

Comment: @Brian Correct. Does not work. It is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the natural maps $\phi\colon V\to V\times V$ sending $v\mapsto (v, v)$ and the map $\psi\colon V\times V\to V$ sending $(v_1,v_2)\mapsto Tv_1+Sv_2$

Then $(T+S)(U)=(\psi\circ \phi)(U)$ while

$T(U)+S(U)=\psi(U\times U)$

We know that $ (T+S)(U)\subseteq T(U)+S(U)$ so that the two spaces are equal if and only if they have the same dimension:

$\dim ((T+S)(U))=\dim(U)-\dim(\ker (\psi\circ \phi))$

while

$\dim (T(U)+S(U))=2\dim(U)-\dim(\ker(\psi))$

(Here $\psi$ and $\phi$ are restricted on $U\times U$ and $U$ respectively)

Thus

$\dim(\ker(\psi))-\dim(\ker (\psi\circ \phi))=2 \dim(U)-\dim(U)=\dim(U)$

Remember that

$\ker(\psi)=\{(v_1,v_2)\in U\times U: Tv_1=-Sv_2\}$

and so it’s the fibered product of $T$ and $-S$, $U\times_{T,-S} U$

and

$\ker(\psi\circ \phi)=\{ v\in U : Tv=-Sv\}$

whose image with respect to $\phi$ is the diagonal $\Delta$ intersected with $ U\times_{T,-S} U$

Another equivalent condition is that

$\dim(\ker(\psi)/\phi(\ker(\psi\circ \phi)))=\dim(U)$

and

$\frac{U\times_{T,-S} U}{\left(\Delta\cap U\times_{T,-S} U\right)}=\ker(\psi)/\phi(\ker(\psi\circ \phi))\cong U$

Comment: You wrote $(T+S)(U) = (\psi \phi)(U) = \psi (TU, SU) = T^2 U + S^2 U$, I don't see why this is the case?

Comment: @gen thank you, now I’ve corrected

Comment: @gen let me know what do you think. I translated the condition in terms of kernels because usually is easier to compute them :)